# setup php + sql server on win7

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a SQL server running on Windows 7. Downloaded PHP and uncommented the mssql-extension. Now Apache fails to start up. When I comment the mssql-extension again, it starts up fine.

I did some research and tried copying ntwdblib.dll to system32 dir, and to the apache/bin dir, but that doesn't solve the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Error messages? Eventlogs? Apache logs? SQL-Server logs? Version numbers? Editions? 32bit or 64bit (of OS and software)?

Comment: If you're new to this, try XAMPP (but if you're planning on using this in a large-scale environment, you might want to research security vulnerabilites). It will hopefully reduce your headaches. If you want specific help, please post error logs and version numbers, as the previous poster said. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make the assumption that you are also running PHP on Win 7 (not 100% clear from your post). If that is the case, you can use the SQLSRV extension: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20098. This post will give you some idea about the differences between the mssql and sqlsrv extensions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/03/08/mssql-vs-sqlsrv-what-s-the-difference-part-1.aspx.

If/when you download the extension, you'll find several .dll files included. Since you are running Apache, you will need a vc6 compiled version of the driver. This topic has more infor about which file to use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx

Comment: brian_swan: Thanks - that did work indeed. I got it working, although I needed to adapt my DBA-layer to use the new commands.